# How to serialize this variable?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a software scanning program and it warns me like this: "Make "**dataSource**" transient or serializable."

I want to know how to **serialize** **dataSource** variable?

```
private DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) SpringUtil.getContext().getBean("dataSource");
```

Please, someone make this dataSource serializable. I only want to see how it is done. Do not comment on any other rules.
Why do you make negative comments on this question huh?

Comment: What output are you expecting from serialization? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a software  scanning program and it warns me like this: "Make "dataSource" transient or serializable."

Comment: which spring version are you using? seems an old bug

Comment: That must be because that variable is part of a class that is serializable. In order for this class to be serializable, all its attributes must be either serializable (must be serialized with the class) or transient (are ignored during serialization).

Comment: @Jordi Castilla, Spring version is 3.0.5.RELEASE, but I think, spring version is not important here. I just wanted to know how to serialize "dataSource" thats all.

Comment: @StarCrafter simply **you don't want to serialize datasource**, your headaches with the spring framework will be eternal.... Making it transient makes much more sense and can be achieved with making daos and services that use datasource transient.

Comment: @StarCrafter 1st... sorry but I thought SO is a free forum so I will keep posting where I think I should, 2nd, I am actually trying to help, if the answer is not what you expect, I'm sorry, but that's it, datasource is a Spring framework own class and you cannot serialize it easily... that's the answer to your question.

Comment: @StarCrafter again.... if you want to solve your question great, but first you need to figure what you problem is, and you don't have a clue of what is going on in your app, so please, check documentation and understand why I say you **don't want to serialize `DataSource`**

Answer (score 0):

The Serialization API doesn't worry about private variables. Its purpose is to convert your object to a binary representation in a file or some other kind of storage that can be reconstructed later.

Please visit here for detail information: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html

Comment: But this is not a kind of storage thing. Yes, Serialization API does not worry, but my scanning sofware majorly worries :)

Comment: You can not serialize the dataSource object here unless the class DataSource itself implements serializable interface. If you can modify the DataSource class to be serializable then it is good else you will have to go other way by making the dataSource varible transient.

Answer (score -1):

Some "live" (with broad internal live) class / objects are not serializable by design (and never will). approximately says "services" (have no interesting data itself, but can provide data on dynamic basis)

How to serialize data from tomorrow ? How to serialize active TCP socket?

Professionals pls forgive too much simplicity in this anwser ;)